# Why is "I'm knowing" incorrect?

Tags: present-continuous, stative-verbs

If "I'm thinking" is correct, why isn't "I'm knowing" correct in formal English?

*think+ing = thinking* is correct
*know+ing  = knowing* isn't correct

Why?

Comment: I'd prefer an actual answer from a real grammarian, but I think it's just a matter of common usage. "I'm thinking", like "I'm eating" is present tense. Knowledge, on the other hand, isn't really being acquired right the second you're speaking, you knew it already. If I wasn't in danger of sounding a bit language-ist, I'd call it an "Indianism".

Comment: 'thinking' is an activity, while 'to know' is a state - either you know or you don't.

Comment: A related question on EL&U: [Verbs not normally used in the present continuous](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/237282/80039) In general, we don't use present continuous with states, emotions, and general realities. There are lists that include more categories than those three but those other categories tend to have a lot of exceptions.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm no linguist, but CGEL categorizes both *think* and *know* as (stative) verbs of cognition, emotion, and attitude, and comments that while none of them excludes the progressive aspect, they differ regarding how easily they take it (and which grammatical meaning they can convey). *Think* is simply not as restricted as *know*, which, the authors remark, is essentially confined to one specific interpretation of the dynamic meaning (the *waxing/waning* case) illustrated in *He claims that fewer and fewer students are knowing how to write English when they come up to university*.

Comment: See pp.162–170 in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002).

Comment: Intelligence does not **continue** to work.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct use of "is having"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150653/correct-use-of-is-having)

Answer (score 6):

Verbs can be considered to be either *action* verbs or *state* verbs. Action verbs, are the verbs used to convey an action, eg run, jump, dance, fight, etc. State verbs, however, usually do not convey an action but they convey information about our ideas, thoughts, feelings and existence, eg think, feel (as in emotion, not as in touching), know, believe, be or have.

State verbs are rarely used in the continuous tense. Action verbs are often used in this tense. This is because the continuous indicates that something is happening now (although it may have commenced in the past), and will probably cease at some stage in the future. So, it contains an implied message that whatever is being done is temporary. This is reasonable for action verbs; in the absence of perpetual motion, we expect most actions to cease at some stage.

A state, as opposed to an action, has a more permanent character associated with it, eg if you know something then, assuming what you know is correct, it is not likely that you will suddenly cease knowing. (Please note that "knowing" at the end of the previous sentence is a participle, not the continuous form of the verb to know.)

So, whereas a native English speaker will say 'I am riding my bike', or 'I am going into town', it is unlikely that they would say 'I am knowing Mr Smith', or 'I am loving my house'. They would more likely say, 'I know Mr Smith, or 'I love my house'.

There are exceptions to what I have said about state verbs, but it usually involves state verbs when they are used to describe non-permanent states. e.g. You should not say,"I am having a car", but you could say,"I have a car". However, it it is acceptable to say, 'I am having a good time', because that is a only temporary state. Similarly you might say, 'I am being quiet', but not 'I am being alive'.

Answer (score 1):

We use [present simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-simple) to describe the way things **are** (and for a few other things), and we use [present continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous) to describe what we are **doing**.

[Stative verbs](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/stative-verbs) like know and feel are used to describe the way things are, rather than an action, so we always use present simple- "I know". If you look at the definition of **[know](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know)**, you will see that it says *not continuous*.

**[think](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/think)** is not a stative verb, so we can use both simple present (to describe the state of having an opinion) and present continuous (to describe an activity):

> I think that television is boring. - *present simple- the way things are*
> Please don't disturb me... I am thinking. - *present continuous- what I'm doing now*

---

Note that the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/knowing) provides this definition of the adjective **knowing**: "showing that you know about something, even when it has not been talked about". It would be grammatically correct to use this adjective to say "I am knowing", but it is more often used to describe a gesture rather than a person:

> She gave me a knowing smile.

Answer (score 0):

To think is an action which you can do in either present or general.

"I think that .." means it is your general opinion.

However, you can't know something in present. What does "knowing right now" mean?

Has your brain just started to function and enabled you to know it? No way, no sense.