# have to vs "to be" + having to

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Although I understand the English language pretty well, I have trouble understanding the subtle difference in between,

1. I have to go
2. I am having to go.

Could somebody clarify?

Comment: *I am having to go* is "Indian English", completely non-idiomatic for actual mainstream native Anglophones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct use of "is having"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150653/correct-use-of-is-having)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know what you meant, but disagree with your choice of wording. There are plenty of Indian (and other South Asian) native English speakers, and due to long occupation, Indian English is not less "mainstream" than any other colonized-nation's dialect. We would consider Canada, Australia, South Africa, and the US to all be "mainstream" native speakers with dialectal differences but not inaccuracies. India is not different.

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon: Nonsense. Chatgpt says *the number of people for whom English is the first language or the "mother tongue" is likely to be in the lower end of the spectrum, possibly in the tens of thousands, rather than hundreds of thousands.* That's a pitifully small proportion of 1.3 *billions* actual Indians! I'm not saying sources like *The Times of India* don't write "valid" English - but probably even they won't have many native Anglophones on the payroll! And to a first approximation, Times of India journos will be *fluent* compared to hundreds of millions who "just get by" in English.

Comment: Indians often use stay for live at a place. Where do you stay? They also use present progressively in a different way. So what? And these uses are highly systematized and systematic. And by the way: I find myself having to go to the office a lot this summer when I usually don't. In this case, perfectly "mainstream" native Anglophone,

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I have to go.
> 2. I am having to go.

No mainstream native says "I am having to go".

To say "I need to go" or "I must go", we use #1.

Comment: No native of the UK or US at least, other countries may vary (India).

Comment: Speakers of "Indian English" are almost *never* "native Anglophones". And *very few* learners would wish to (unwittingly?) learn non-standard IE usages rather than "mainstream" English.